# Verificar horários coincidentes dentro de um array

Tags: php, laravel

Estou trabalhando com um *agrupamento de tamanho indefinido* de arrays, onde cada array (filho) possui um outro agrupamento de tamanho indefinido de horários (com horário inicial e final) para a execução de determinada tarefa, no exemplo abaixo há somente dois agrupamentos de horários para cada array filho, mas dentro da execução do sistema pode haver vários, tanto para a quantidade de horários, quanto para a quantidade de tarefas.

O problema é... Como posso verificar se estes horários coincidem de uma forma "mais simples" sem ter que abusar de recursividade e laços de repetições? pois neste sistema nenhuma tarefa pode ser executada enquanto uma outra está sendo executada.

Nenhum horário pode ser repetido, e também não pode ter início no período de outro conjunto de horários (horário inicial e final), e caso haja pelo menos um horário coincidente, a verificação pode parar.

A regra entre os horários é semelhante a um "humano" "profissional", que logicamente não pode está em dois lugares ao mesmo tempo.

Basicamente a verificação deve parar quando: `($horario_inicial_atual >= $horario_inicial_anterior OR $horario_inicial_atual <= $horario_final_anterior) AND ($horario_final_atual >= $horario_inicial_anterior || $horario_final_atual <= $horario_final_anterior)`

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["initial"]=>
      string(5) "08:00"
      ["final"]=>
      string(5) "12:00"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["initial"]=>
      string(5) "14:00"
      ["final"]=>
      string(5) "18:00"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["initial"]=>
      string(5) "08:00"
      ["final"]=>
      string(5) "12:00"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["initial"]=>
      string(5) "14:00"
      ["final"]=>
      string(5) "18:00"
    }
  }
}
```

Obs: Caso esta lista anterior seja muito complicada de ser trabalhada para esta verificação, pode ser utilizado este formato também:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["initial"]=>
    string(5) "08:00"
    ["final"]=>
    string(5) "12:00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["initial"]=>
    string(5) "14:00"
    ["final"]=>
    string(5) "18:00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["initial"]=>
    string(5) "08:00"
    ["final"]=>
    string(5) "12:00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["initial"]=>
    string(5) "14:00"
    ["final"]=>
    string(5) "18:00"
  }
}
```

Obs 2: Caso não tenha como fugir de loops, qual seria a melhor prática?

Obs 3: Posso modificar o array de qualquer forma, pois ele serve somente para verificação, depois é descartado.

Obs 4: Só preciso saber se há ou não horários coincidentes, sem mais detalhes mesmo, o importante é saber se é verdadeiro ou falso.

Comment: Não vai ter muito como fugir de loops. De onde vem estes dados? Talvez possa tratá-los na camada de banco de dados, facilitando a sua vida no momento de verificar as condições.

Comment: Vem direto de um "calendario" criado pelo usuário, essa verificação deve ocorrer antes de ser salvo no banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lógica é simples:

1. Percorre a lista (`foreach`) - poderia ser `array_map`;
2. Converte os dados para um objeto `\DateTime`;
3. Verifica se o intervalo não coincide com algum já verificado anteriormente (`array_walk`);
   3.1. Se houver conflito, dispara a exceção (`\Exception`);
4. Adiciona o intervalo em questão a lista;
5. Retorna a lista de intervalos;

Função `schedule`:

```
if (!function_exists('schedule'))
{
  /**
   * Retorna a lista de intervalos conforme a lista de entrada. Houvendo conflitos
   * nos horários, uma exceção é disparada.
   * 
   * @param  array  $items  Lista de intervalos de entrada
   * @return  array  Lista de intervalos de saída
   * @exception  \Exception  Quando houver conflitos nos intervalos
   */
  function schedule (array $items)
  {
    $_schedule = [];

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
      $initial = \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $item["initial"]);
      $final   = \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $item["final"]);

      array_walk($_schedule, function ($value, $key) use ($initial, $final) {
        if (
          ($initial >= $value["initial"] && $initial <= $value["final"]) ||
          ($final >= $value["initial"] && $final <= $value["final"])
        )
        {
          throw new \Exception("{Mensagem de erro}");
        }
      });

      $_schedule[] = compact("initial", "final", [$initial, $final]);
    }

    return $_schedule;
  }
}
```

### Exemplos

#### Exemplo 1:

Considerada uma entrada válida:

```
$data = [
  0 => [
    "initial" => "08:00",
    "final" =>"12:00",
  ],
  1 => [
    "initial" => "12:00",
    "final" =>"18:00",
  ]
];
```

O retorno da função será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [initial] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2017-03-06 08:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [final] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2017-03-06 12:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [initial] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2017-03-06 12:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [final] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2017-03-06 18:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

        )

)
```

#### Exemplo 2:

Considerada uma entrada inválida, com conflito nos horários:

```
$data = [
  0 => [
    "initial" => "08:00",
    "final" =>"12:00",
  ],
  1 => [
    "initial" => "10:00",
    "final" =>"11:00",
  ]
];
```

O retorno da função será algo como:

```
Uncaught Exception: {Mensagem de erro} in /run_dir/repl.php(68) : eval()'d code:26
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}(Array, 0)
#1 /run_dir/repl.php(68) : eval()'d code(28): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /run_dir/repl.php(68) : eval()'d code(48): schedule(Array)
#3 /run_dir/repl.php(68): eval()
#4 {main}
  thrown
```

Se não tratada a exceção.

---

### Função retornando true/false

```
if (!function_exists('schedule'))
{
  /**
   * Retorna a lista de intervalos conforme a lista de entrada. Houvendo conflitos
   * nos horários, uma exceção é disparada.
   * 
   * @param  array  $items  Lista de intervalos de entrada
   * @return  array  Lista de intervalos de saída
   * @exception  \Exception  Quando houver conflitos nos intervalos
   */
  function schedule (array $items)
  {
    $_schedule = [];

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
      $initial = \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $item["initial"]);
      $final   = \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $item["final"]);

      try {
          array_walk($_schedule, function ($value, $key) use ($initial, $final) {
            if (
              ($initial >= $value["initial"] && $initial <= $value["final"]) ||
              ($final >= $value["initial"] && $final <= $value["final"])
            )
            {
              throw new \Exception("{Mensagem de erro}");
            }
          });
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
          return false;
      }

      $_schedule[] = compact("initial", "final", [$initial, $final]);
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: É possível retornar um valor bool ao invés de um exception?

Comment: Basta capturar a exceção dentro da função e retornar falso. Adicionei ao final da resposta.